# My Logo is cut and don't show it's full size (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my logo(pic1[image])
I don't understand why is not shown correctly.
The first time it doesn't work when I tried to resize the window(from PC view to mobile) Then after  I upload the site on netlify I see that it doesn't work correctly on PC view.
Down bellow is my code for this.
[image]

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: var(--smallFont);
    max-width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body{
    line-height: 1.2;
}
.container{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    /* text-align: center; */
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 1.2rem;
}
.container::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#bg-video{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
  

.logo{
    margin-top: 10vh;
    height: auto;
    width: 350px;
    
}
```

```html
<body>


    <div id="Acasa" class="container">

        <video autoplay muted loop id="bg-video" Set_VideoRate()>
            <source src="2 (3).mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>

       
        <div class="content">
            
           
            <div class="titlu">
                <img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="logo">
                
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working absolutely fine.

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: var(--smallFont);
    max-width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body{
    line-height: 1.2;
}
.container{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    /* text-align: center; */
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 1.2rem;
}
.container::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#bg-video{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
  

.logo{
    margin-top: 10vh;
    height: auto;
    width: 350px;
    
}
```

```html
<body>


    <div id="Acasa" class="container">

        <video autoplay muted loop id="bg-video" Set_VideoRate()>
            <source src="2 (3).mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>

       
        <div class="content">
            
           
            <div class="titlu">
                <img class="logo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjqWj.png" alt="logo">
                
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: https://hbfcarshine.netlify.app/

Here is the link, when I open in google chrome or Android(my phone, it is look like I show you in the Print screen)

Comment: @andrei0292 I opened your link and the image still looks fine.

Comment: @andrei0292 on the website behind the link the code is different. delete on the css of the 'img'-element the "object-fit: cover;", so the image is no longer cropped, and delete "aspect-ratio: 4/3;", so the image is not squeezed.

Comment: Yes that was the problem :) thx man, I have down in the code other img , In html have a class name, but in my css I add prop. to img not to class, and that was the problem :) Thank you !

Comment: @andrei0292 Glad to hear that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

better use "max-width" instead of width on ".logo" for better browser copatibility. in my firefox dev edition (101.0b9) on mac your code works correctly.

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: var(--smallFont);
    max-width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body{
    line-height: 1.2;
}
.container{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    /* text-align: center; */
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 1.2rem;
}
.container::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#bg-video{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
  

.logo{
    margin-top: 10vh;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 350px; /* better use max-with for better brower copatibility */
    
}
```

```html
<body>


    <div id="Acasa" class="container">

        <video autoplay muted loop id="bg-video" Set_VideoRate()>
            <source src="2 (3).mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>

       
        <div class="content">
            
           
            <div class="titlu">
                <!--img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="logo"-->
                <img class="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" alt="logo">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: hbfcarshine.netlify.app 
here is the link, can you please tell me how it looks like ? because for me it looks like in the first print screen.